# Class has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 64.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes

Tags: java, tomcat, xampp

I am facing a problem on loading my Java servlet using the Xampp server on Windows 11. I have installed Java 2.0 64-bit and jre 1.8 64-bit on my system.
Class has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 64.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load the class.

Xampp server gives an error message when I try to load my Java servlet.
[image]

Xampp version: 3.3.0

Using command prompt java gives version:

java version "20.0.1" 2023-04-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.1+9-29)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.1+9-29, mixed mode, sharing)
[image]

whereas in the system control panel Java gives:
Version 8 Update 381 (build 1.8.0_381-b-09)

[image]

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: Make sure that Java 20 is listed *before* Java 8 in the PATH environment variable.